# python 3.x - "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Upon running this code,

```
 #Silent Auction

    class Auction:

        def __init__(self):
            self.reserve_price = 30
            self.highest_bid = 0
            self.highest_bidder = ""
            self.namelist = []
            self.bidlist = []

        def reserve_price(self):
            print("Hello. The reserve price is ${}".format(self.reserve_price))

        def new_bidder(self):
            LOOP = 0
            while LOOP == 0:
                name = input("What is your name? 'F' for FINISH ")
                if name.upper() == "F":
                    LOOP = 1
                else:
                    bid = int(input("Hello {}. What is your bid? ".format(name)))
                    if bid > self.highest_bid:
                        self.highest_bid = bid
                        self.highest_bidder = name
                        self.namelist.append(name)
                        self.bidlist.append(bid)

                    else:
                        print("Sorry {}. You'll need to make another higher bid.".format(name))
                        print("Highest bid so far is ${:.2f}".format(self.highest_bid))


        def auction_end(self):
            if self.highest_bid >= self.reserve_price:
                print("The auction met the reserve price and the highest bidder was {} with ${:.2f}".format(self.highest_bidder, self.highest_bid))
            else:
                print("The auction did not meet the reserve price")
                n = len(self.namelist)
                for i in range (0, n):
                    print("{} bid ${:.2f}".format(self.namelist[n], self.bidlist[n]))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        auction1 = Auction()
        auction1.reserve_price()
        auction1.new_bidder()
        auction1.auction_end()
```

I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Work\Year 13\13DIP\91637 Programming\Silent Auction.py", line 46, in <module>
    auction1.reserve_price()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: This is not a free debugging service. You have to do a little more work than dumping your entire code and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your function and your instance variable the same thing.

Change

```
def reserve_price(self):
```

to

```
def print_reserve_price(self):
```

I know if you come from java you can do things like this and it knows the difference, but in python functions are first class citizens and you can refer to them directly. i.e.:

```
In [2]: x = lambda i : i * i
In [3]: x
Out[3]: <function __main__.<lambda>>
In [5]: x(2)
Out[5]: 4
```

However I can also overwrite it

```
In [6]: x = 5

In [7]: x
Out[7]: 5
```

Which is what happens above when you set `self.reserve_price` in your init method.

Comment: This is terrible asking behavior and I'm DV'ing just for encouraging it. Sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize for your opinion; that's what communities are about. I just tend to think if the question has enough code to reproduce the error in a small enough context with the exact error message, and the user is possibly new, I might as well help them. I do think I can provide more context in my answer as to what is going wrong. I myself have a lot of "oh DUH" moments that another pair of eyes can often catch.

Comment: Oh wow I feel so dumb now. I don't exactly understand the In/Out stuff but I understand what you mean that my function name was bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you overwrite your `reserve_price` method in the `__init__` method

check this illustrative example

```
>>> class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.fun = 42
        def fun(self):
            print( "funny" )

>>> a = A()
>>> a.fun
42
>>>
```

the solution is simple, change the name of one of them.